# How to use FormatDateTime to return a default date concatenated with current year?

Tags: delphi, date, delphi-2007, formatdatetime

I'm using Delphi 2007.

I need write a FormatDateTime function that always return 01/01/ to a TDateEdit box (DevExpress component) as EditValue.

I've already tried...

```
tcxDateEdit1.EditValue := FormatDateTime('01/01/'+ 'yyyy',now);
```

and

```
tcxDateEdit1.EditValue := FormatDateTime('01/01/yyyy',Now);
```

but none of them worked.
It result in an error of converting variant of type string to double.
"Could not convert variant of type (String) into type (Double)"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm only guessing but your `EditValue` property seems to be of `TDateTime` (or `TDate`) type (while `FormatDateTime` returns a `string`). If that's true you could try the following:

```
tcxDateEdit1.EditValue := EncodeDate(YearOf(Now), 1, 1);
```

See also: [YearOf](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/DateUtils.YearOf), [EncodeDate](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/SysUtils.EncodeDate), [FormatDateTime](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/SysUtils.FormatDateTime) documentation